# What versions of Windows will .Net 4.0 support?

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.0, compatibility

What versions of Windows is Microsoft planning to support with .NET 4.0?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151782/will-ms-drop-support-for-xp-in-net-4-or-5

Comment: @ChrisF, he is a asking about future compatibility with .net 4 and 5 under XP, I just want a list of windows versions that 4 is going to run under. I wouldn't call this question an exact duplicate. Similar yes, but duplicate no. Also he never really gets a straight answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The official list is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(VS.100).aspx).

Supported operating systems are:

- Windows XP (SP3)
- Windows Vista (SP1)
- Windows 7
- Windows Server 2003 (Base & R2)
- Windows Server 2008 (Base & R2, all editions, not supported in Server Core Role)
- Windows Small Business Server 2003 & 2008

Notable operating systems not supported include XP Media centre edition, XP Tablet PC edition and Windows 2000.

(The .NET Framework Client Profile is not supported on IA-64 systems.)

[Updated list for final release]

<strike>([see here (beta 1)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ee2118cc-51cd-46ad-ab17-af6fff7538c9&displaylang=en#Requirements))</strike>
<strike>([see here (beta 2)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DED875C8-FE5E-4CC9-B973-2171B61FE982&displaylang=en#Requirements))</strike>

Comment: No problem. Don't take it as a rock solid guarantee though. I'd say it's pretty unlikely, but not entirely impossible that supported platforms may change for the final release.

Comment: Noted, but I think it will be highly unlikely for Microsoft to dump support for any version after beta testing on that system.

Comment: The 4.0 beta is supported on Windows 7, not just the Windows 7 RC.

Comment: @Richard: Yeah, probably, I guess they just haven't updated the page since the beta was released.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [.NET 4.0 Beta 2 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DED875C8-FE5E-4CC9-B973-2171B61FE982&displaylang=en), it's supported on Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista and Windows XP.

Comment: Slightly more update then Simon's answer due to it being beta 2. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, new releases of .net are supported with all operating systems currently supported by Microsoft.  For example, .Net 2.0 base supports Windows 98.  But Windows 98 end-of-life'd in 2006 and when .Net 2.0 sp1 came out in 2007 support for Windows 98 was dropped, even though it would probably work just fine.

That means .Net 4.0 is *likely* to be supported on XP sp2 and newer (and **not** base XP or XP sp1, which have both end-of-life'd) even though it would probably work just fine on older XP releases.

The big question is service pack 2 and whether they find a delay-worthy bug in .Net 4.  Service Pack 2 reaches end-of-life on July 13, 2010.  If they have to delay .Net 4 even a few months, I'll give good odds that it won't support XP sp2.  But if it makes it's release schedule it likely will support XP sp2.

Comment: I once examined the IE8 for Server 2003 installation package (released in March 2009 just before SP1 was going out of support) and it was set to require SP2, but they still left shdocvw.dll etc in the package even though SP2 already have the updated version!